# Get test result/run attachments using TFS REST API

Tags: rest, api, tfs

Created the URL to fetch the test result/run attachments from the TFS and tested the URL in fiddler but could not get the response data, 
it gives an error

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

How to solve this error and need to get data for test result/run attachments?

URL:

```
GET https://{organization}/{ProjectName}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{resultId}/attachments?api-version=2.3
```

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use?

Comment: I am using TFS 2018 U2 @ShaykiAbramczyk

Comment: I changed the api-version to 4.1-preview it worked for me @ShaykiAbramczyk .

Comment: Great! You can post is as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET https://{organization}/{ProjectName}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{resultId}/attachments?api-version=4.1-preview
```

I changed the version of Api to 4.1-preview, then i can able to fetch the build test run attachment from TFS.